# Detecting android contact changes since last application run

Tags: android, android-contacts

What is the best way to check for contact changes since the last time the application was executed?

The only solution I cam see is to make a copy of the RawContacts and check the VERSION field of each contact the next time the application is executed, but it looks like a very complex and slow solution.

Comment: Maybe with the DIRTY flag, but I am not very sure with that...

Comment: @gustavobob Have you managed to solve this problem?

Comment: @gustavogb have you find an answer?